# How to input multiple karma reporters in command line?

Tags: karma-runner

Is it possible to input more than one reporter I want to use from the command line?

I have tried the following combinations none of seems to work

```
> karma start karma.conf.js --reporters progress summary

> karma start karma.conf.js --reporters progress, summary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found out! Turns out I should not have whitespace between reporters

That is, the input to the command line should looks as following

```
> karma start karma.conf.js --reporters progress,summary
```